# Can we change the css assigned to div after a button click event occurred?

Tags: asp.net, css

I am working on ASP.Net site where I would like to realign the various html controls after button click occurs. Can I do that by replacing current css with new css ? And how can I associate that element with  new css in code ?

Comment: You can do this in JavaScript. Are you using a framework like jQuery or mootools?

Comment: yes. I am using jQuery v1.7.1

Comment: In that case, isotrope has your answer below.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer if it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have classes ready to be switched between, you can

```
$(selector).addClass('classname');
$(selector).removeClass('classname');
```

..this will alter the classes of the selected element(s)

Or you can

```
$(selector).css('propertyname', 'propertyvalue');
```

...this will modify inline styles on the selected element(s).

Edit: To complete my answer a bit...

Let's say the clickable element in a div with an id of "clickables_container", your clickable element's id is "clickable_element" and the element you want to modify has a class of "change_me"...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#clickables_container').on('click', '#clickable_element', function() {
       $('.change_me').removeClass('olderclassnametoremove');
       $('.change_me').addClass('additionalclassname');
       $('.change_me').css('background-color', 'blue');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do it like this:

```
SomeControl.Attributes.Add("class", "myCssClass");
```

If you want to do it with jQuery, you can also manipulate the css of the elements:

```
$('#SomeControl').removeClass('myOldCssClass');
$('#SomeControl').addClass('myCssClass');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but you have to have additional class in next `.css` file you're going to apply.
Let's say you have the following html:

```
<body>
<div class="a">bla-bla</div>
...
<div class="b"></div>
</body>
```

Also you have such `.css` file:

```
.a {
//styles here
}

.b {
//some other  styles
}
```

And now you want to change look and feel of all elements on the page. To do so, you're adding new class to the top-level element, such as html or body

```
<body class="c">
<div class="a">bla-bla</div>
...
<div class="b"></div>
</body>
```

So, you also need to have such styles in your `.css` file

```
.c .a {
//changed styles here
}

.c .b {
//some other changed styles
}
```

Hope it helps.